# wordpress menu to display only if current page is descendant of a given page

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, navigation

The site im trying to develop has two root pages. 
Being the nav structure:

- A (LEVEL 0)

  - A1 (LEVEL 1)

    - A1.1  (LEVEL 2)
    - A1.2  (LEVEL 2)
  - A2 (LEVEL 1)

    - A2.1  (LEVEL 2)
    - A2.2  (LEVEL 2)
  B (LEVEL 0)
  - B1 (LEVEL 1)

    - B1.1  (LEVEL 2)
    - B1.2  (LEVEL 2)
  - B2 (LEVEL 1)

    - B2.1  (LEVEL 2)
    - B2.2  (LEVEL 2)

What I need is to show **navA if the current page is a descendant of A**, and likewise only **show navB if the current page is a descendant of B.**

I tried creating two separate menus in wordpress backend, but only the mainNav one would show. 
The menus are generated as navigation using wp_nav_menu($args) as shown below.

```
echo "<div class='main_menu' data-selectname='".__('Select a page','avia_framework')."'>";

                        $avia_theme_location = 'avia';
                        $avia_menu_class = $avia_theme_location . '-menu';
                        $args = array(
                            'theme_location'    => $avia_theme_location,
                            'menu_id'           => $avia_menu_class,
                            'container_class'   => $avia_menu_class,
                            'fallback_cb'       => 'avia_fallback_menu',
                            'walker'            => new avia_responsive_mega_menu()
                        );

                        **wp_nav_menu($args);**

   echo "</div>";
```

Is there a way to implement this functionality from the backend? Else, any suggestion on what road to go down to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
function menu_set_parent( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) {
    $last_top = 0;
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $key => $obj ) {
        // it is a top lv item?
        if ( 0 == $obj->menu_item_parent ) {
            // set the key of the parent
            $last_top = $key;
        } else {
            $sorted_menu_items[$last_top]->classes['parent'] = 'parent';
        }
    }
    return $sorted_menu_items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'menu_set_parent', 10, 2 );
```

Try this it will add parent class to parent . add this in your`functions.php`